# Signal handler statement not printed

Tags: c, unix, signals

While going through signals, I found that statement inside the handler was not printed. Here is the code I used:

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"signal.h"
#include"unistd.h"
void handlerSIGINT(int sig)
{
    if(sig == SIGINT)
       printf("\nFinally caught SIGINT...");
}
int main()
{
    printf("Hello ... soon u'll receive a signal");
    if(signal(SIGINT, handlerSIGINT) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        printf("error in SIGINT  handling");
    }
    while(1)
        sleep(1);
    /*now press control + C to see the effect */
    return 0;
}
```

I got the following output when I run the program :

```
[root@node1 mytest]# ./a.out
^CHello ... soon u'll receive a signal
^CFinally caught SIGINT...
^CFinally caught SIGINT...
^CFinally caught SIGINT...
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./a.out
```

My confusion is : When I first pressed "Ctrl+C" it didn't print the message in the handler i.e. "Finally caught SIGINT..." .But from the second time it started printing the message. Can anyone explain why is this happening...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void handlerSIGINT(int sig)
{
    if (sig == SIGINT)
        printf("\nFinally caught SIGINT...");
}
```

Here in the signal handler, the output is not terminated by a new line, and by default, the standard output is line buffered, so it's only shown when the next time it sees the `\n` in the beginning. Change it to:

```
printf("Finally caught SIGINT...\n");
```

you would probably see the result as expected. Note, however, [you should avoid using `printf` in a signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler).